# Should i use a variable or a param?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I know that variables in XSLT cannot be updated in for each. But i do not know how to handle this situation in my code.

My xml looks like the below :

```
<Detail>
 <name>A</name>
 <time>123</time>
 <number>456</number>
 <duration>789<duration>
</Detail>
<Detail>
 <name>A</name>
 <time>235</time>
 <number>579</number>
 <duration>15<duration>
</Detail>
<Detail>
 <name>A</name>
 <time>479</time>
 <number>282</number>
 <duration>3468<duration>
</Detail>
<Detail>
 <name>B</name>
 <time>324</time>
 <number>234</number>
 <duration>248<duration>
</Detail>
```

As you can see, the name tag for the first 3 Detail section is same and the name tag for the 4th detail section is different.
My output should look something like this :

```
A
123   456   789
235   579   15
479   282   3468
B
324   234   248
```

The time, number, duration is printed in separate cells of the row.
The name is a single row.
The challenge now is that how do i avoid the name tag for the second and third detail section since the value is same as the name tag in the first detail section.
Below is a snippet of my code.
I have created a variable call T3nameitem which i have declared as xxx.
I am checking if the name tag is not equal to the variable then we print the row. I am also updating the variable in the if condition so that in the second iteration, the name tag and the variable will be equal and wont enter the if condition. This logic should work in other languages but have no clue how to do it here in xsl fo.

```
<xsl:variable name="T3nameitem" select="'xxx'">
<xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:if test="name != $T3nameitem">
     <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell > 
       <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
       </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    <xsl:variable name="T3nameitem" select="name"></xsl:variable>
    </xsl:if>

        <fo:table-row >
        <fo:table-cell><fo:block >
          <xsl:value-of select="time"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell> <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="number"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell> <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="duration"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a grouping question - see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info